# Can I now add a class in the anchor of my menu item with Wordpress 5.4?

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I am using the following code in my functions.php file:

```
function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
return preg_replace('/<a title="All"/', '<a title="All" class="addition-of-class-name"', $ulclass, 1);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','add_menuclass');
```

So, as you can see, I am checking for a menu item anchor and then adding a class in the anchor that comes after the menu item snippet that I have configured in my Wordpress site.

```
<li class="class-added-by-wp-menu-item-already">
   <a class="CAN-I-ADD-A-CLASS-WITH-THE-NEW-FIELD-HERE-NOW?">
   </a>
</li>
```

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/02/25/wordpress-5-4-introduces-new-hooks-to-add-custom-fields-to-menu-items/

Can I now do this with the new functionalities in Wordpress 5.4 / to be precise:

```
wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields
wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields_customize_template
```

Or did I misread?

Comment: Those new filters are for adding fields when editing the menu item. They don't change anything about adding classes to the HTML.

Comment: Why do you need it to be on the anchor specifically? The built in CSS class option targets the `li` but you can then target the anchor via css with `.yourclass > a`, the same with javascript